# Web 8 Single Server Installation - Can't log in to CM

Tags: web8

After successful installation. Not able to login to CMS.
Its showing nothing but just the box where we enter CMS credentials with a line"Your Connection to this site is not private".
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be caused by the "loopback check" security feature of Windows Server. If you are mapping different names to the localhost interface, which is a common enough technique for single server test set-ups, you will need to make registry entries before you can connect using these names. (Note: this will only be a problem if you are connecting from the server itself. Connections from off the box should work fine if this is indeed what is going on.)

[This article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_foxhole/archive/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way.aspx) explains what you need to do.